# Flutter chart with percentege in the middle

Tags: flutter, charts, syncfusion

I'm developing mobile app using flutter. I want to display a chart as follows. It shows the progress of the some attributes. So I have only attribute with their percentage. I tried charts_flutter and syncfusion_flutter_charts. But I couldn't implement middle percentage value as it is.

[image: chart with description]

Comment: plz add the code you have used and explain where did you get stuck

Comment: I'm new to flutter. I only tried examples in those libraries. I want to know how implement chart as the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) is useful in this scenario. I've used this library in one of my app for the same purpose.

You can achieve the basic look by adding the following code:

```
CircularPercentIndicator(
    radius: 60.0,
    lineWidth: 5.0,
    percent: 0.5,
    center: Text("50%"),
        progressColor: Colors.green,
)
```

You can do a lot of customisation with this library, check their documentation for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be achieved using the **annotations** feature of the circular chart widget. You can find the sample from the below link,

https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/blob/master/lib/samples/chart/circular_charts/doughnut_series/doughnut_with_center_elevation.dart

And for more information on the properties available in **CircularChartAnnotation**, find the API reference below,

https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/CircularChartAnnotation-class.html

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion.